# Why this css code works only in Chrome?

Tags: css, printing, stylesheet

I am adding `class="noPrint"` for elements to hidden them

It is working fine in `chrome` but when I browse in `Mozilla` and `IE`, by default elements are not visible.

I need those elements to be hidden on print not by default.

Only with chrome it is working but in other browsers it is not

Here is my CSS Code :

```
 <style type="text/css" media="print">
      .noPrint{ display: none; }
      .yesPrint{ display: block !important; }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use media queries to style things differently for print.
Something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print {
  .noPrint{ display: none; }
  .yesPrint{ display: block !important; }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Still the same the elements which has to be hidden in a print window are hidden by default on page load.

Comment: The code above only applies for print, so maybe you are doing something else wrong. Please provide a jsfiddle where you can show us your problem at a smaller level.